# Extjs Training

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, frontend, javascript-framework

Our company is starting a major re factor of its front end Javascript code. We have decided to use Extjs as a framework and would like to invest in some training for several of our employees. We are mostly looking for Extjs specific material, but some advanced architecture wouldn't hurt. We are happy to fly our employees on location.The problem is that there are just too many options available on the web. Where do you even begin?

Comment: If you can speak Portuguese, these are really good and free!  http://www.loiane.com/2011/11/curso-de-extjs-4-gratuito/

Answer (score 5):

Fig leaf software is a credible alternative http://training.figleaf.com/Courses/sencha.cfm you can contact Arya Heidari [arya at figleaf dot com], they are very flexible in their training options.

Another credible alternative is Jay Garcia's company, Modus. He wrote Ext-JS in Action http://moduscreate.com/offerings/training/extjs/

Like I commented in another answer, $2000/person/weekend is not so steep. You get what you pay for.

Answer (score 4):

You can start from Ext JS docs page if you want to use the last Ext JS 4 version: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide

And you can buy Ext JS in Action, second edition, Meap edition here: http://manning.com/garcia3/

Its the best Ext JS book I have ever seen, Jesus Garcia explains every detail of Ext JS framework.

Comment: Thumbs up to the extJS4 docs.  They are really good.  Especially if you go thru the guies, example code and supplementary tutorials (MVC one is a must have).  They also have lots of training material online:

Comment: Modus Create, Jay Garcia's company, also offers Ext JS Training [Ext JS Training](http://moduscreate.com/offerings/training/extjs/) which is a good resource to take a look at

Answer (score 3):

Ext, LLC, stewards of ExtJs, provide [Enterprise Training](http://extjs.com/support/training/extjs/).

Comment: Thanks Steve. We looked into them and they are about $2000 / person for one weekend. Seemed a bit steep, but it may be our only choice.

Comment: That doesn't sound so steep for me. Don't cheat yourself by buying cheap labor.

Answer (score 2):

Extjs is a nice framework for rapid front end development.  However, There are a considerable amount of bugs in 4.0.7.  Many of these are addressed in 4.1.  I went from zero understanding of Extjs and javascript to being able to build a full powered web app in about 1.5 months. I am a single developer mind you, so I have to do backend/front end programming.

You only really need a basic understanding of javascript and css.  The examples in the Extjs documentation are very good and that is how I was able to learn so quickly.  The most challenging part of using Extjs for me was getting it to communicate with the backend.

Answer (score 0):

where are you located? How many employees would attend the training? (What is your backend technology?)
I have been giving two-day trainings (0.5 day Javascript, 0.5 day Ext JS, 1 day hands-on on Ext JS parts/widgets you most probably will be working with) before and would be happy to do the same for you!

To what are you referring with "there are just too many options available on the web"?

I'm right now located in Valencia, Venezuela (40 min away from Aruba, if you want to be very nice to your employees ;) or any other location would be fine with me.)

Cheers,
Steffen

s dot hiller at caprireleases dot com

Comment: Ben,

let me add this note to make sure you got my point and something helpful out of it:
My point is that the official Ext training is not your only choice, you always could look for independent consultants (such as me) that can offer Ext JS training for a lower price, but still high value.

Cheers,
Steffen

Comment: If you're going to offer professional services, you need to post a link to your website, doesn't look very credible without something that shows why you're a good Ext-JS trainer.